# insert into database values from arraylist

Tags: c#, database, arraylist, insert

Platform c#
degerlerkutu is column name of  databese table.
kutular is control names from form,
i want to insert record to database from arraylist, help :) how to can run this code ?

```
Control[] kutular = {Sirket_Unvani, Vergi_Daire, Vergi_No, yetkili, 
                     Yetkili_Telefon, Telefon, faks, adres, CariDosyaadi };

string[] degerlerkutu = { "Sirket_Unvani", "Vergi_Daire", "Vergi_No", "yetkili", 
 "Yetkili_Telefon", "Telefon", "faks", "adres" ,"il" , "ilce", "CariDosyaadi" };

ComboBox[] Combolar = { il, ilce };

ArrayList kaynak = new ArrayList();
ArrayList hedef = new ArrayList();
kaynak.Clear();
hedef.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < kutular.Count(); i++)
{
    kaynak.Add(kutular[i].Name +".Text");  
}

for (int i = 0; i < Combolar.Count(); i++)
{
    kaynak.Add(Combolar[i].Name+".SelectedValue"); 
}

for (int i = 0; i < degerlerkutu.Count(); i++)
{
    hedef.Add(degerlerkutu[i]);
}

OleDbCommand cmd2 = 
       new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO cariler (" + string.Join(",", hedef) 
               + ") Values (" + string.Join(",",kaynak) + ")", anafrm.bag);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i see is that you need to have single quotes around strings.  Hope this helps!

Values ('" + string.Join("','",kaynak) + "')"